# Is it possible for a pulse doppler radar(full coherent) to integrate multiple pulse with different carrier frequencies (during an integration)?

Tags: radar

Especially for digital (modern) radar?

Also is it possible (in the same configuration to integrate multiple pulses with the same carrier frequency with intrapulse modulation (each pulse has a different modulation pattern between each other ( frequency modulation for example or phase modulation))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what is done in the stepped frequency radar. See Einstein: "Generation of High Resolution Radar Range Profiles and Range Profile Auto-Correlation Functions Using Stepped-Frequency Pulse Train" (yes, Einstein but not Albert) in https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA149242.pdf or any pn coded radar *after* pulse compression.

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11432-009-0087-8 
for HPRF pulse doppler stepped frequency radar

Comment: OK, what is your point about [that](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11432-009-0087-8) article?

Comment: i wasn't sure if stepped frequency radar could be used with pulse doppler processing

also can it be used for medium/long range application?

Comment: With a power-limited transmitter and operating with a single antenna the longer the range the more appropriate is to use stepped frequency radar. As I said above pulse doppler processing is *after* the pulse or spectrum compression and then it does not matter whether it was pseudo noise phase coded or frequency coded or not coded at all, either would work in principle. The difference lies in hardware/software and also in some secondary details of the environment, such as multipath reflection, jamming, meteorological phenomena, etc.